# Line that goes from end of text to end of block on middle of height

Tags: html, css

I have some headings and want to add line that goes from end of text in that heading to end of that heading block. Line should be in the middle of line height.

Something like this

```
+---------------+
| some text ----|
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo-element is ideal for that:

```css
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: .25em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Text</h1>
```

Modern version (using flexbox instead of positioning)

```css
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
h1::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  height: 2px;
  margin-left: .25em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Text</h1>
```